# Why can I not save currentTime() to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I try to automatically get the `currentTime()`on button click, but the issue I have at the moment is that I cannot access `player` when the button "create" is clicked. It returns `undefinied`

How can I get access to `player.currentTime()` when create is clicked?

```
var player;

$('.start').on('click', function (event) {
    initializePlayer("test.mp4");
    $('.create').show();
});

$('.create').on('click', function (event) {
    var start = player.currentTime();
    // start is always undefined
    console.log("start is ".start);

    startConverting(start);
});

function startConverting(start) {
    // converting
}

function initializePlayer(src) {
    player = videojs('media', {
        fluid: true,
        controls: true,
    });

    player.src({
        type: "video/mp4",
        src: src,
    });
}
```

I have been looking at this for a long time and can't see where my problem is. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Edit:

I realized that if I `console.log(player.currentTime())` it would output the time. Now, why can I not pass the value to `var start` and it is being undefined?

Comment: `console.log("start is ".start);` does not do what you think it does. You want `console.log("start is " + start);`. What you wrote will construct the string `"start is "`, then try to find a property `start` on it, which does not exist. The result is thus the same as `console.log(undefined)`.

Comment: It's JavaScript, not PHP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition